# Shift and number key issue

Tags: autohotkey

Wanted a simple script where `MButton` mapped to hitting the number row key <kbd>8</kbd> then holding `RButton` until released.

```
$MButton::
SendInput {8}
SendInput {RButton Down}
return

$MButton Up::
SendInput {RButton Up}
return
```

But there's a problem; if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is being held, the script does nothing. So I added the wildcard to ignore modifiers:

```
*$MButton::
SendInput {8}
SendInput {RButton Down}
return

*$MButton Up::
SendInput {RButton Up}
return
```

But now the script **releases <kbd>Shift</kbd>** on its own when `MButton` is pressed. How can I make it work ignoring modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380171/send-existing-modifiers-with-a-key-in-autohotkey

`{Blind}` passes whatever modifiers are being held to the sent inputs, in a wildcard match.

```
*$MButton::
SendInput {Blind}{8}
SendInput {Blind}{RButton Down}
return

*$MButton Up::
SendInput {Blind}{RButton Up}
return
```

That seems to work for me.